# Why can I import nothing in .m file

Tags: objective-c, import, implementation, jsonmodel

**Edit:**

I finally found out that I import a header file which has indirect import for the `JSONModel.h` file.

---

Today I tried AppCode and it gives me some hint that some import is useless.

I found out that it seems that some subclasses of `[JSONModel][1]` can omit import statement of its own header file in the implementation file (`.m` file) and compile successfully.

For example:

`TestModel.h`

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface TestModel : JSONModel

+ (JSONKeyMapper *)keyMapperWithJsonToModelDic:(NSDictionary *)jsonToModelDic;

@end
```

`TestModel.m`

```
@implementation TestModel

+ (JSONKeyMapper *)keyMapperWithJsonToModelDic:(NSDictionary *)jsonToModelDic {
    return jsonToModelDic;
}

@end
```

So when can I omit the import statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the *Prefix header file* (`ProjectName-Prefix.pch`) which contains the necessary system header files and is applied to all implementation files by Xcode.

Comment: You are right about the previous example! But there are other cases that is not handled by the prefix.pch file. Please see my modifications.

Comment: You are brilliant! I finally found out I have other header file which import the header file indirectly.